# Spark Scratch Space

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, caching, memory, memory-management

I have a cluster of 13 machines with 4 physical CPUs and 24 G of RAM.

I started a spark cluster with one driver and 12 slaves.

I set the number of cores by slaves to 12 cores, meaning I have a cluster as foloowing :

```
Alive Workers: 12
Cores in use: 144 Total, 110 Used
Memory in use: 263.9 GB Total, 187.0 GB Used
```

I started an application with the folowing configuration :

```
[('spark.driver.cores', '4'),
 ('spark.executor.memory', '15G'),
 ('spark.executor.id', 'driver'),
 ('spark.driver.memory', '5G'),
 ('spark.python.worker.memory', '1042M'),
 ('spark.cores.max', '96'),
 ('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'),
 ('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'),
 ('spark.executor.cores', '8'),
 ('spark.default.parallelism', '48')]
```

I understand there are 15G of RAM by executor with 8 task slot and a parallelism of 48 (48  = 6 task slot * 12 slaves).

then I have two big files on HDFS : 6 G each, (from a directory of 12 files of 5 blocks of 128 Mb each) , with a 3x replication factor.
I union these two files => I get one dataframe of 12 GB I think but I see a 37 G reading input through the IHM :

[image]

That could be the first question : Why 37 Gb ?

Then as the execution time is too long for me, I try to cache the data so that I can go faster. But the caching method never finishes, here you can see it is already 45 minutes before the end (Vs 6 min not cached !):

[image]

So I try to understand why, and I see the usage of Memory/Disk on the storage section of the ihm :
[image]

So there are some part of the RDD that are staying on disk.
Furthemore I see the executors may still have free memory : 
[image]

And I notice on the same "storage" page that the size of the RDD has jumped :

```
Storage Level: Disk Serialized 1x Replicated
Cached Partitions: 72
Total Partitions: 72
Memory Size: 42.7 GB
Disk Size: 73.3 GB
```

=> I understand : Memory Size: 42.7 GB + Disk Size: 73.3 GB = 110 G !
=> So my 6 G file has transformed on 37 G and then on 110 G ???

But i try to understand why is there still some memory left on my executor, and I go to the "err" dump of one, and I see :

```
18/02/08 11:04:08 INFO MemoryStore: Will not store rdd_50_46
18/02/08 11:04:09 WARN MemoryStore: Not enough space to cache rdd_50_46 in memory! (computed 1134.1 MB so far)
18/02/08 11:04:09 INFO MemoryStore: Memory use = 1641.6 KB (blocks) + 7.7 GB (scratch space shared across 6 tasks(s)) = 7.7 GB. Storage limit = 7.8 GB.
18/02/08 11:04:09 WARN BlockManager: Persisting block rdd_50_46 to disk instead.
```

And Here I see that the executor want to cache a 1641.6 KB  block (only 1Mo !) and I can't because there is a ["scratch space"] of 7.7 Gb "shared across 6 tasks".

=> What is a "scratch space" ? ?

=> The 6 tasks => comes from the parallelism of 48 / 12 = 6

And then I come back to the app information, and I see that the count that lasted 48 min read only 37 Gb of data ! (The 48 min are clearly used to cache the data too)
[image]

When I do a count on the cached dataframe I have a 116G input read : 
[image]

And at the end of the day, the time saved by the cached count is not that impressive, here are 3 duration :
4.8 ' : count on cached df
48'   : count while caching 
5.8'  : count on not cached df (read directly from hdfs)
[image]

So why is it so ? 
Because the cached df is not that much cached : 
[image]
Meaning more or less  40 Gb in memory and 60 Gb on disk.

I am surprised because at 15G / executor * 12 slaves => 180 Gb of memory, and I can cache only 40 Gb ... But in fact I remember that the memory is splitted :

30% for spark

54% for storage

16% for shuffle

So I understand that I do have 54% * 15G for storage, ie 8.1 G, meaning that on my 180 Gb, I only have 97 Gb for storage. Why do I have 90 - 40 = 50 G not used then ?

Oups... This is a long post ! 
Plenty of questions... Sorry...